# Custom component and access to backing bean

Tags: java, jsf-2, managed-bean, custom-component

Is it possible in JSF2 from a custom component (in method encodeBegin) to access to the FacesContext and managed beans?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Even more, the `FacesContext` is available as method argument of [`encodeBegin()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeBegin%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method.

Then, to access managed beans, use `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`.

```
Bean bean = (Bean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{beanName}", Bean.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

public Object getSessionBean(String beanName) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        sessMap = context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
        return sessMap.get(BeanName);
}